# Adding e-mail address in BCC in a PHP code

Tags: php, bcc

I'm trying to figure out how to add an e-mail address in BCC.
Since I added more "$headers" to add the blinded e-mail address, the entire code doesn't function anymore.

```
<?php
// put your email address here
$youremail = 'xxx@xxx.it';

// if the url field is empty
if(isset($_POST['url']) && $_POST['url'] == ''){


// prepare message 
$body = "Nuovo messaggio dal sito web :

Nome:  $_POST[name]
Azienda:  $_POST[company]
Telefono:  $_POST[phone]
Email:  $_POST[email]
Messaggio:  $_POST[message]";

if( $_POST['email'] && !preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $_POST['email']) ) {
  $headers = "From: $_POST[email]";
} else {
  $headers = "From: $youremail";
}
$headers .= "Bcc: yyy@yyy.com\r\n";

mail($youremail, 'Richiesta Informazioni dal Sito Web', $body, $headers );

}
?>
```

Comment: I usually just use PHPMailer http://phpmailer.worxware.com/ does everything I need it to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add line breaks to the first line of your headers too:

```
if( $_POST['email'] && !preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $_POST['email']) ) {
  $headers = "From: $_POST[email]\r\n";
} else {
  $headers = "From: $youremail\r\n";
}
$headers .= "Bcc: yyy@yyy.com\r\n";

mail($youremail, 'Richiesta Informazioni dal Sito Web', $body, $headers );

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you forgot your line endings on your `From` header.

```
if( $_POST['email'] && !preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $_POST['email']) ) {
  $headers = "From: $_POST[email]\r\n";
} else {
  $headers = "From: $youremail\r\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks also to you :)